# How to change text of th of table in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have table like below

```
<table>
 <tr> <th>Document</th> <th>...</th></tr>
 <tr><td>...</td>... </tr>
 ...
</table>
```

Now I want to change the text of th "Document" to "Marketting Document/URL"BY jQuery... Please help me!!!

Comment: what you have tried ?? add code

Comment: @all: thanks a lot for supporting me. I want to accept all the answers

Comment: @user2179026, Mark answer whichever help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: change <th> to <th id="documentId">Document</th> then using Jquery, you can make $("#documentId").html("Marketting document..."), hope it will help you

Answer (score 8):

```js
$("table tr>th:first").html("Marketting Document/URL");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr><th>Document</th> <th>1</th></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>3</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Try something like this:

```
console.log($("table tr>th:first").html("Marketting Document/URL"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this : use jQuery selector to get first `tr` and then fist `th` inside it. Then use `.text()` or `.html()` method to update your desired value.

```js
$(function(){
  $('table tr:first th:first').text('Marketting Document/URL');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Document</th>
    <th>second header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>first td</td>
    <td>second td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give an id to the "th"

```
 <table>
 <tr> <th id="thtext">Document</th> <th></th></tr>
 <tr><td></td> </tr>
```

Then in the javascript function add this

```
 $("#thtext").html("Marketting Document/URL");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this `first()` [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L39j5Lcs/)

```
$(function(){
  $('table tr>th').first().html('Marketting Document/URL');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// For First th for first tr

```
$(function(){
  $('table tr:first').find('th:first').html('Marketting Document/URL');
});
```

// For First th for all tr

```
$(function(){
  $('table tr').find('th:first').html('Marketting Document/URL');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search the text that have "Document" in your table heading as following code and replace the value with the new value.

```
<script>
 $(function(){
   var m = $('table tr th:contains("Document")');
       m.text('Marketting Document/URL');
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to other solutions, one may also like to skip the first row (normally the **header** row). To do that, we can approach it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('table tr').not(':first').find('th:first').html('Some Text');
});
```

A practical use case may be to insert **row** numbers in the row headers (as would be found in *spreadsheet* applications), wherein we may loop through each row and add the loop `index` as the **row** number ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ilus.jpg)).